# Retrieving a UTC datetime from a data source -- putting it into a Joda DateTime object and persisting it to MongoDB. What is the best way?

Tags: java, mongodb, jodatime

I am pulling data from an external source into my program and it has an ISO8601 Date attached to it but one of our requirements is that the hour/minutes/seconds get set to zero. This happens before I receive the date. So I get this from the data.

```
2013-05-17T00:00:00.000Z
```

for instance. I am then putting that value into a Joda DateTime object called "businessDay". I do some processing based off of this value but then I need to persist it to MongoDB.

Since a Joda DateTime object is not serializable I need to put the DateTime object into a Date object and persist it to Mongo (and reverse that when it comes out).

When I use Joda in this way
`businessDay.toDate()` -- I receive a Java Date object but it is

```
Sun May 19 20:00:00 EDT 2013
```

and businessDay printed out normally is

```
2013-05-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

It converts it to my local time zone, which is then making it the previous day.
What I want is to convert the DateTime object into a Date object that retains the values.

I've been trying a bunch of things with DateTimeFormatter but I can't get it to work at all. I've also been deleting all of my efforts otherwise I would paste them here but I've been doing this all day to try to figure this out.

Thank you for any assistance.

EDIT:

Showing method that converts a String Date into a Joda DateTime object.

```
 private DateTime asDateTime(String value) {
        // Was experiencing an issue converting DateTime to date, it would convert to localtime zone
        // giving me the wrong date. I am splitting the value into its year/month/day values and using a dateFormatter
        // to give me an appropriate format for the date. Timezone is based on UTC.
        String[] splitValue = value.split("-");
        String[] splitDay = splitValue[2].split("T");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(splitValue[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(splitValue[1]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(splitDay[0]);
        DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).withDate(year, month, day).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using - in particular, a Java `Date` object doesn't print out as "2013-05-16T08:00:00.000Z" at all. Where did you get that string from? Note that the `Z` indicates UTC, which *isn't* the same as your local time zone...

Comment: Hmm, I guess the date I am receiving back is from the data I receive which is generated with Joda Time and turned into a String. I will paste the code that is converting that String into a DateTime object.

Comment: I updated the values to reflect their TRUE representation. I added the  joda date I am getting and the ".toDate()" represetnation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you've just got a date, I would suggest using `LocalDate` rather than `DateTime`. However, I think you've misunderstood what `java.util.Date` does:

> It converts it to my local time zone, which is then making it the previous day.

No, it really doesn't. Your `DateTime` value is precisely 2013-05-20T00:00:00.000Z. Now a `java.util.Date` is *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It doesn't have the concept of a time zone at all. It's equivalent to a Joda Time `Instant`.

When you call `toString()` on a `Date`, *that* converts the instant in time into your local time zone - but that's not part of the state of the object.

So both your `DateTime` and your `Date` represent midnight on May 20th UTC. I don't know what MongoDB is then doing with the value, but just the conversion from Joda Time to `java.util.Date` has *not* performed any time zone conversion for you.

Comment: The issue I'm having with MongoDB is in fact the issue of a Joda time object not being "serializable". That is the reason it needs to be converted to Date.

Comment: Also for clarity now that I'm on my laptop and not mobile phone. I do need to have the UTC date stored in MongoDB and not my local time.

Comment: @envinyater: But you're converting it to a `Date` correctly. It should be fine, assuming MongoDB can propagate that `Date` appropriately. Don't be fooled by the output of `Date.toString()`, basically.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I found out that it wasn't an issue of the Dates it was a completely different issue. MongoDB can accept a Java Date and will convert it to UTC format automatically.

My fault for creating this post before looking at this problem from different angles.

Do I accept the other answer and give the bounty? Just curious if that is the correct thing to do on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If it helped you, you should. If it did not it's your call! Alternatively you can accept your answer and give the bounty to the other answer.

Comment: @envinyater UTC is not a format. You might find it helpful to reread Jon Skeet’s answer and then learn more about handling date-time in programming.